# Program displaying array class name while using getter method

Tags: java, arrays, encapsulation, setter, getter

I just want to scan and display array using getter and setter method.It works fine in setter but when i am trying to call getter method instead of displaying array elements it display array class name. how can i display array elements using getter method??

```
    public class ArrayElements {

    private int[] arrayElements;

    public int[] getArrayElements() {
        return this.arrayElements;
    }

    public void setArrayElements(int[] arrayElements) {
        this.arrayElements = arrayElements;
    }
}
```

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayElements arrayElements = new ArrayElements();
        int[] element = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter Elements :");
        for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            element[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        arrayElements.setArrayElements(element);
        System.out.println(arrayElements.getArrayElements());
    }

}
```

```
Enter Elements :
10 20 0 45 56

[I@299a06ac
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayElements.getArrayElements()));
```

Other solutions you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 1):

To display the elements of your array you should use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayElements.getArrayElements()));
```

Your call just shows the memory address of your int array.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to other answers, explaining *why* do you get strange on first sight results.

Everytime you call `System.out.println(object)` and pass some `object` there, internally a `toString()` method is called within `println()`. So the call is equal to `System.out.println(object.toString())`. It's done for getting valid string representation of the object you're trying to print.

An array is a reference type, and it's of type `Object`. You don't override `toString()` method for array, so its default implementation falls down to `Object` class.
Implementation of `Object` class `toString()` method:

```
public String toString()
{
      return getClass().getName()+"@"+Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

As you can see here this method prints out name of class, symbol "@" and hashcode in hex format.

See reference here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-tostring-method-in-java/[enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-tostring-method-in-java/)

Comment: thank you for giving me good explanation about the problem :). i tried Arrays.toString and it worked

Comment: @HarshPithadia, consider accepting answer if you think it was useful for you=) Maybe not even my answer, other peoples` answers are valid too and closer to your initial question.